# Two types of satipaṭṭhāna - which has jhana?

Tags: reference-request, jhana, satipatthana

In [Mindfulness, Bliss, and Beyond](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XKN6C8),  Ajahn Brahm writes -

> The Buddha taught two types of satipaṭṭhāna. The **first type is supported by jhāna** and leads to enlightenment in a short time.

Which satipaṭṭhāna is the **first type**, and where can it be found ? (By "two types" does he mean the two versions DN 22 and MN 10?)  Please reference both types and specify which is the "first type".

Comment: There is some explanation here, as in Jhanas of the present moment mindfulness: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAt3J3-wEOI

Answer (score 1):

**Which satipaṭṭhāna is this, and where can it be found?**

[This is the direct path for purifying of beings, for overcoming sorrow and distress, for vanquishing pain and distress, for attaining the right approach, for realizing Nirvana – namely, the four applications mindfulness’](https://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/articles/SatipatthanaSutta.pdf)

**Was this the satipaṭṭhāna which led to the Buddha's awakening?**

[My heart, thus knowing, thus seeing, was released from the fermentation of sensuality, released from the fermentation of becoming, released from the fermentation of ignorance. With release, there was the knowledge, 'Released.' I discerned that 'Birth is ended, the holy life fulfilled, the task done. There is nothing further for this world.'](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.004.than.html)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Ajahn Brahm sounds strange to me. I imagine there is only one type of Satipatthana, which means to "*establish mindfulness*". What this means is whatever body, feelings, mental states or Truth/Reality is/are experienced; the mind '*remembers*' ('*sati*') to not have covetousness & distress towards those bodies, feelings, mental states or Truth/Reality.

Jhana (*Appanā Samādhi*) is merely a higher level of feelings (2nd satipatthana) and mind (3rd satipattana) than experienced with the lower Neighborhood Concentration (*Upacara Samadhi*) of Anapanasati. Therefore, mindfulness is established towards jhana the same as towards any other experience, as explained in many suttas, such as below:

> *Whatever qualities there are in the first jhana... he remained unattracted & unrepelled with regard to those qualities, independent,
>   detached, released, dissociated, with an awareness rid of barriers.*
>
> *MN 111*